# Conditional Expectation of $X$ under $X+Y$ where $X,Y$ are iid exponential random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Given two independent exponential distributed random variables $X,Y$ what is the condintional expectation $E[X| X+Y]$.

This is my exercise and I don't really see how to solve it.
I know that I need the shared density function $f_{X|X+Y}$ then I get:

$$ E[X|X+Y=z] = \frac{1}{\int f_{X|X+Y}(x,y)dx} \int x f_{X|X+Y}(x,y)\text{d} x $$
The the wanted expectation is just
$$ E[X|X+Y] = \frac{1}{\int f_{X|X+Y}(x,Y)d x}\int x f_{X|X+Y}(x,Y) d x $$

But I don't get the shared density function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good start, but you are not quite there.   Replace that $Y$ with $Z-X$ and you obtain:

$\begin{align}
\mathbf{\text{Let:}}\quad Z & = X+Y
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E(X\mid X+Y)
 & = \int_0^Z x f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Z-x)\operatorname d x
\\[1ex]
 & = \dfrac{
\displaystyle\int_0^Z x f_X(x)f_Y(Z-x) \operatorname d x 
}{
\displaystyle \int_0^Z f_X(x)f_Y(Z-x)\operatorname d x
}
\end{align}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I suppose for $\int_0^Z xf_X(x)f_Y(Z-x) dx = \frac{\lambda^2Z^2}{2}exp(-\lambda Z)$ is the solution?

Comment: Ok, I suppose the solution is $\frac{1}{2}(X+Y)$